# Elegant way to find maximum return value of a function in N trials

Tags: python

I found the following solution to find the maximum return value of an example function given `N` trials:

```
import random
def example_function():
    return random.randint(0,9) * random.randint(0,9)
N=3
max([example_function() for _ in range(N)])
```

The solution feels clumsy and inefficent. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: How is creating a list for N calls and using `max()` at all clumsy? It's the most reasonable and simple approach.

Comment: I agree with @BRemmelzwaal, this is a completely acceptable, Pythonic, and arguably elegant approach. The only other option would be to use Numpy or Scipy, which can generate the entire array of random values at once.

Comment: I'd use a generator rather than a list. There's no need to store all of them in memory at the same time.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Actually a good suggestion, I think that _would_ be a more elegant approach.

Comment: Given the simplicity of `random.randit(0, 9)` and it only being called in one place it feels a little silly to have a `random_int` function at all.  `max(random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(N))`?

Comment: @Chris It's presented as an example function. We may assume it was used for illustration purposes.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal exactly, this is an example function. I will update the question.

Comment: "elegant" and "clumsy"... did you read my question today? :-)

Comment: @Kelly pure coincidence that we used the same wording! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is totally acceptable and pythonic. There is one possible, in some cases significant, improvement that prevents storing intermediate results: using generator expression instead of list comprehension.

```
import random


def example_function():
    return random.randint(0,9) * random.randint(0,9)


N=3

max(example_function() for _ in range(N))
```

The change is just removal of brackets, but this means that instead of list construction and finding its maximum, values are generated in the process of searching for the maximum.

You can read more about generators [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) and about generator expressions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions). More details about generators and generator expression are in the [PEP-255](https://peps.python.org/pep-0255/) and [PEP-289](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/).

Answer (score 1):

Your initial code gets the job done simply and quickly, and is easy to read. My only concern is that you are creating a list to hold all the values in memory, and only then passing it to max. Instead use a generator expression.

But when you need an iterable, I'd take a glance at the itertools documentation first. And sure enough we see "repeatfunc" in the itertools recipes.

https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#recipes

When I put it all together, it looks complicated, but in practice we'd just be importing repeatfunc from https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/:

```
from itertools import starmap, repeat
from random import randint

# repeatfunc from itertools recipes
def repeatfunc(func, times=None, *args):
    if times is None:
        return starmap(func, repeat(args))
    return starmap(func, repeat(args, times))


# call a function n times and return the max
def example_function():
    return randint(0, 9)

print(max(repeatfunc(example_function, 3)))
```

Comment: I wonder why they don't just put the recipes in itertools.

Comment: Partly because they're already in more-itertools. And partly because they don't want too much in itertools. I think that was mentioned in the [discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/add-batching-function-to-itertools-module/19357) of a recently added itertools.

Comment: That also links [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/why-does-itertools-have-recipes/17622]), which talks exactly about this. Note especially [Erlend's reply](https://discuss.python.org/t/why-does-itertools-have-recipes/17622/3).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm definitely going to pip install that.